# Made an edit to homebrew formula, now I want to save it

Tags: homebrew

So I've made an edit to the tmux formula in homebrew, but now I'm starting to think about how I can keep that change between machines without forking and maintaining my own version of homebrew.

If I do fork homebrew, I would just have to edit and install script to point to my location, but would the formulas locations still be maintained?

So I guess my question is what are my options here? Should I fork homebrew or just make a note of the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your own tap. The easiest way is to create a repository on GitHub called `homebrew-self`. Your custom formula goes in the root of the repository. Then, you can use it in Homebrew by running

```
brew tap <your github username>
```

If you're modifying a formula that's already in Homebrew, though, the easiest (and best) way is to [submit a pull request](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/How-To-Open-a-Homebrew-Pull-Request-(and-get-it-merged).md#how-to-open-a-homebrew-pull-request-and-get-it-merged) containing your changes.